# When using Macbook as monitor for iPhone camera it only shows portrait orientation

Tags: macos, iphone, camera, ios

I'm using a Macbook Air M2 2022 + iPhone 12 Mini.

When I rotate the camera 90º the Macbook screen looks like this (camera image is sideways):

[image]

Just watched a [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrohcOxXavA) where someone demonstrates this and it works as you would expect (monitor shows landscape when rotating phone).

Either I'm doing something wrong, missing a setting, or one (or both) of my devices don't support this for some reason.